# Remove access of the media devices in js

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, getusermedia, simple-peer

I used the getUserMedia function to get access to my camera and mic, but now I want to remove the access when I leave the particular page or component in react

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: videoConstraints, audio: true })
```

I tried to get access when the user accessed the component but now I want to switch off the entrance of media devices

Answer (score 3):

a stop on the track should be ok to release it.

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: videoConstraints, audio: true })
stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop())
```

If by access you mean permissions, it's on browser side to decide when you are enabled or not to request a media.